# Batch File to rename multiple files and move to folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need help with batch file that can rename and move files from my c:\SaveAttachments to multiple folders in C:\Users\Omer\Documents\

I have about 5000 files in c:\SaveAttachments (.pdf, .doc, .xls)

e.g (aacom_880072_4860914.pdf or .doc or .xls)
e.g (bbcom_880082_4860914.pdf or .doc or .xls)

rename aacom_**880072**_4860914 to **880072** and move it to C:\Users\Omer\Documents\aacom

rename bbcom_**880082**_4860914 to **880082** and move it to C:\Users\Omer\Documents\bbcom

Help on this is greatly appreciated.
I hope I have provided sufficient information to see if this is feasible.

FYI I am beginner in coding batch files so comments on the code are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
set "logfile=U:\logfile.log"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%
>>"%logfile%" echo start at %date% %time%
FOR %%x IN (pdf doc xls) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
   'dir /b /a-d "*_*_*.%%x" '
   ) DO (
    FOR /f "tokens=1,2*delims=_" %%m IN ("%%a") DO IF "%%n" neq "" (
    ECHO(MD "%destdir%\%%m"
    >>"%logfile%" ECHO(MD "%destdir%\%%m"
    ECHO(Move "%%a" "%destdir%\%%m\%%n.%%x"
    >>"%logfile%" ECHO(Move "%%a" "%destdir%\%%m\%%n.%%x"
   )
 )
)
POPD
>>"%logfile%" echo end at %date% %time%

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. Append `2>nul` to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

switch to the source directory
For the required extensions, do a directory scan for files with at least 2 underscores and the extension.
tokenise the name to `%%m` and `%%n`
(belt-and-braces - ensure `%%n` isn't empty)
create the directory and move the file.

[edited to include logging as requested]
[revised edit : omitted `%` and include quotes]

Comment: Thank you, it did exactly what I wanted and thank you for comments on the code.

Comment: how do I save all the output commands into logfile.log and the time date is was executing. Thank you agian

Comment: That should fix it - there was a missing `%` in `>>%logfile%`

Answer (score 0):

If all the files have the same naming convention as you posted this should be relatively easy using a Bash shell script executed within Cygwin.

```
src='/cygdrive/c/SaveAttachments'
dst="/cygdrive/c/Users/Omer/Documents"
for file in $(find $src -type f)
do
    prefix=${file%%_*}
    if [[ ! -e $dst/$prefix ]]
    then
        mkdir -p $prefix
    fi
    name=$(cut -d_ -f2 $file)
    mv $file $dest/$name
done
```

I have not tested this so there might be corner cases I missed, but overall you get the idea.